# Run a regression in a loop with a reactive dataframe in Shiny

Tags: r, for-loop, shiny

I have a syntax issue in Shiny. I want to run a non-linear regression in a loop in which the input data is the reactive dataframe `Update_df1` which is created earlier in in my `server.R` script. The output would be a dataframe containing the prediction values which we then append to the `Update_df1` reactive dataframe to create the `Final_df`. Below is the part of the `server.R` script I cannot make working. Anyone knows how I could handle my issue?

## Update

```
 Age<-reactive({
  prediction<- data.frame(Update_df1()$Site_ID)
  prediction$f_Age <- NA
  colnames(prediction)<- c("Site_ID", "f_Age") 
  for(id in unique(Update_df1()$Site_ID)){
    lm_Age<- try(nlsLM(NEP~offset + A*(1-exp(k*Stand_Age)), data = Update_df1()[ Update_df1()$Site_ID != id,], 
                       start = list(A=  711.5423, k= -0.2987, offset= -444.2672),
                       lower= c(A = -Inf, k =  -Inf, offset= -1500), control = list(maxiter = 500), weights = 1/Uncert), silent=TRUE)
    prediction$f_Age[prediction$Site_ID == id] <- predict(object = lm_Age, newdata =  Update_df1()[Update_df1()$Site_ID == id,])
    }%>% as.data.frame()
})

Final_df<-reactive({
  data.frame(Update_df1(), Age())
})
```

The error message I got is `Warning: Error in data.frame: arguments imply differing number of rows: 126, 0`. The dataframe `Age` seems to be empty.

Comment: You're doing too many things within the `Age()`, I would suggest to break it down into small chunks. Also try to avoid using `.` in you're reactive expressions.

Comment: Well the `lm.age` object and the creation of the `f_age` variable are dependent to each other, so I am not quite sure how I could break down the reactive expression. Any ideas?

Comment: I mean there are created in the same loop.

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the way around.

```
Age<-reactive({
  prediction<- data.frame(Update_df1()$Site_ID)
  prediction$f_Age <- NA
  colnames(prediction)<- c("Site_ID", "f_Age") 
  for(id in unique(Update_df1()$Site_ID)){
    lm_Age<- try(nlsLM(NEP~offset + A*(1-exp(k*Stand_Age)), data = Update_df1()[ Update_df1()$Site_ID != id,], 
                       start = list(A=  711.5423, k= -0.2987, offset= -444.2672),
                       lower= c(A = -Inf, k =  -Inf, offset= -1500), control = list(maxiter = 500), weights = 1/Uncert), silent=TRUE)
    prediction$f_Age[prediction$Site_ID == id] <- predict(object = lm_Age, newdata =  Update_df1()[Update_df1()$Site_ID == id,]) 
  }
  return(prediction)
})

Final_df<-reactive({
  data.frame(Update_df1(), Age())
})
```